# NCrunch and PostSharp Logging clash

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, log4net, postsharp, ncrunch

I have been happily using NCrunch and PostSharp (param validation) in a project for many months now

I just added PostSharp Logging via log4net to my project and now NCrunch is complaining about the .psproj files that were added:

> My.App.psproj (0): Cannot find the plug-in configuration file
>   "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\NCrunch\3116\6\packages\PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics.4.0.39\tools\PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics.Weaver.dll".

I have cleaned, rebuilt, trashed the NCrunch cache, all to no avail - NCrunch is still failing.

The ReSharper test runner is still able to run all the tests succesfully.

Has anyone else seen this problem? Can it be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to fix this, you need to add the required files to the NCrunch "Additional files to include" configuration.

1. In the NCrunch Tests window, right click on the project which is failing to build and select `Configure selected component`
2. Under the `General` section, select the `Additional files to include` item and click the `...` button
3. Click the `Add File(s)...` button
4. Browse to where the `PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics.Weaver.dll` file is located (in my instance, as I am using NuGet for PostSharp, it is in `packages\PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics.4.0.39\tools`  under my solution directory
5. Click `Open`
6. Repeat steps 3 to 5 for `PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics.Weaver.Log4Net.dll` (in `packages\PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics.Log4Net.4.0.39\tools`)
7. Click `OK`
8. Close the `NCrunch Configuration` window

NCrunch is now able to build and run all tests

Answer (score 0):

This error message is generated by PostSharp. The *.psproj file contains a relative path to the diagnostics weaver plug-in. Apparently, NCrunch changes the current directory used to resolve the relative path, and consequently PostSharp cannot find the referenced plug-in.

This is combatiblity issue that you can also report to PostSharp team on http://www.postsharp.net/support